# How to Add Colorbox Pop Up for Miva Quick View Button

Tags: jquery, colorbox, miva

I'm trying to replicate the look of Nextopia's Quick View pop up. They are using Colorbox. An example on our site is at http://www.hatsinthebelfry.com/category/womens-hats.html

This is the Miva code for the current button (test page here: http://www.hatsinthebelfry.com/category/NEXtest.html)

Current Button:

```
<input type="button" value="Quick View" onClick="divwin=dhtmlwindow.open('divbox&mvt:product:id;', 'div', 'somediv&mvt:product:id;', '&mvt:global:JSProdName;', 'width=600px,height=560px,top=20px,scrolling=1, center=1'); return false" style="cursor:hand;" class="nxt_moreinfo">
```

This is the code I got from Jack Moore (the developer of Colorbox), but this is to open an html page. I need to open a div.

```
<button onclick='$.colorbox({href:"example.html"}); return false;'></button>
```

Can anyone tell me how to call the miva code correctly in the colorbox syntax?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you asking about this:

```
$.colorbox({ href: '#inline_content', inline:true });
```

And html:

```
<div style='display:none'>
     <div id='inline_content'>test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The part I'm really having trouble with is putting all of that Miva code into the correct syntax. I'm not really familiar with either of these methods for the pop up, so I'm not sure what goes where.

Comment: @kaitlynjanine I don't know how your miva code works, but I show example with inline content. If you tell me how this code executes, then probably I could help you.

Comment: &mvt:global:JSProdName; and &mvt:product:id; are variables (think $productName and $productId). Other than that, I can't really wrap my head around how this is working.

Comment: @kaitlynjanine You need to change html-markup (look at example) and your code will look like: `$.colorbox({ href: '#somediv&mvt:product:id;', title: '&mvt:global:JSProdName;', inline:true });`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.colorbox({ 
rel:'mycontent',
inline:true,
href: function(){var url = $(this).attr('href'); return url;}
});

<a rel="mycontent" href="do-something.php?productid=somevalue">Do Something</a>
```

The above allows for a single colorbox reference.